# @media syntax issue can't be resolved in razor page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

```
@@ media print {
    .print-column {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 48%;
        /* Adjust the width as needed */
        vertical-align: top;
    }
}
```

This is how I write code in razor pages. There is no error found but not also working when I load the webpage but a warning is there to show and it is **Unrecognized '@' block type.**

I want to expect that my code should be working. Here is the warning with the screenshot
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Is the space between "@@" and "media" a typo?

Comment: Looks like a typo (`@@ media` vs. `@@media`), but since we already have a question explaining proper syntax closing this one as duplicate instead of a bit more appropriate "typo" closing reason.